# epoll in multi process environment

Tags: file, epoll, descriptor, multiprocess

In my client app I am using epoll and udp socket to receive packet from the server. Client app has two process, p1 and p2.

Using this function to get fd's sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0) ;

In process P1, socket() function returns fd's starting from 4.
P1 has fd's 4,5,6,7,8 etc

In process P2, socket() function returns fd's starting from 4.
P2 has fd's 4,5,6

Now in both the process has same fd's but port number is different.

Both process P1 and P2 uses epoll to read/write.
In this scenario any chance of getting packet to P2 , which actually intended to P1 happens?

Answer (score 0):

No. Each process has its own file(socket) descriptor set. The value of the FDs can be same as one with other process. No issues there. So no way of packet intending for P1 to reach P2.

You can recall that file descriptors 0, 1 and 2 corresponding to stdin,stdout and stderr are open for each process. They aren't unique to process.